# In Vim, what's an elegant way to grab output from the command-line?

Tags: vim

If I'm in Vim and want to get some output from the command-line and tack it onto my current file, I can run this:

```
:! echo "foo" >> %
```

That will append "foo" to my current file, and I'll have to reload.

Is there a more elegant way to do this - have that output go into a buffer that I can paste, for example?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes:

```
:r !echo "foo"
```

See

```
:help :r!
```

That will insert the output of the command after the current line. If you want to capture the command output into a register that you can paste, you can do this:

```
:let @a = system('echo "foo"')
```

Now the output of the command (including the trailing newline) is in register `a`. See

```
:help let-@
:help system()
```

Comment: After looking at the help and experimenting, I see that 1) `:r` is short for "read" (so you can type out 'read' or just 'r' and it's the same command), and 2) doing `:r path/to/foo.txt` will insert the contents of that file after the cursor.

Comment: Also - I didn't know about the `system` call. That's awesome!

Comment: I also didn't know you could manually set registers like `let @a = 'foo'`. One cool idea would be, after doing a search and replace, you could save the search term to a register for pasting elsewhere by doing `let @a = @/` - "make the a register contain what the / register contains, namely, my last search."

Comment: @Nathan Long: You're welcome. Other ways to paste from the / register are 1) to execute `:put /` to put the register contents on the next line and 2) while in insert mode, to type Ctrl-R followed by `/` to insert the register contents at the cursor position. For more on those, see `:help :put` and `:help i_CTRL-R`.